# Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $user_id ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\AllocatedUserPanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm building a livewire component to handle adding new users to a job via the jobs 'show' route. So I have a jobs table, a job_users table and a users table. I use a hasManyThrough relationship which is used to get the user names of the users already allocated to the job. Below the section which shows these I have a dropdown of all users and an add button.

When I click the add button i get the error I mention in this posts title (Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $user_id ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\AllocatedUserPanel)

My livewire file is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Job;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class AllocatedUserPanel extends Component
{
    public Job $job;
    public $users;
    public int $user_id;

    protected $rules = [
        'user_id' => 'required',
    ];

    public function mount( Job $job )
    {
        $users = User::where( 'is_enabled', 1 )->orderBy( 'name', 'asc' )->get();
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->job = $job;
        $this->user_id = 0;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.allocated-user-panel');
    }

    public function addUser( $user_id )
    {
        $this->validate();
    }
}
```

and the blade has this:

```
<div>
    @foreach($job->jobUsers as $user)
        <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
    <form wire:submit.prevent="addUser">
        <select
            name="job.user"
            wire:model="user_id"
            class="p-2 px-4 py-2 pr-8 leading-tight bg-white dark:bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow appearance-none hover:border-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
        >
            @foreach ( $users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <x-jet-button>
            {{ __('Add') }}
        </x-jet-button>
    </form>
</div>
```

It looks like the user_id param is not passed to the livewire component but i do not understand why?

thanks

Comment: Why to pass the `$user_id` to the `addUser` function? I think you don't need this parameter. To fix you would need to add to your blade: wire:submit.prevent="addUser({{ $user_id }})"

Comment: Hi itepifnio, That seems to have got it and I can see the user_id is passed to the component. Sometimes livewire seems like works by hocus pocus. wouldn't have imagined I could pass a form vaiable that way but yes it makes sense...